# Using SCSS with angular library created using angular-cli

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli

I have created an angular library project where I want to use SCSS for styles.

So I have configured

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext scss
```

and this made an entry to **angular.json** file

```
"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
}
```

Now I am using [materialize-css](http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html) UI library in my library components. And it requires to import its SCSS file.

I am not seeing **styles.scss** file where I can import this and my components and other common styles?

I tried creating one and making entry into **angular.json**

```
"styles": ["projects/library_name/styles.scss"]
```

Under `projects` -> `library_name` -> `architect` -> `build` -> `options`

but this is showing error while building the library project

```
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(styles).
```

**Update**

I got [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10869), addressing the same issue if it helps!

Comment: For angular 13+ it's now: ```"style" : "scss"```

Comment: You can import any file into your angular.json `"styles": ["node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Till the date (10-Jan-2019, there is no direct support for global scss in the library even though this is a very common scenario.

From this [discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10869), I got the workaround that I need to bundle it myself. So I used `scss-bundle` to create one big scss file. You can add it using

```
yarn add scss-bundle@next -D
```

and then the script to bundle and run in watch mode

```
"build-lib-watch-styles": "scss-bundle -e \"./projects/lib-name/src/lib/styles/lib-name.scss\" -d \"./dist-lib/lib-name/styles/lib-name.scss\" -w \"./projects/lib-name/src/lib/styles\"",
```

Answer (score 17):

I know it was late but, maybe help with somebody's idea.

1. Create `style.scss` in the library which the same path with the `ng-package.json`.
2. Open `ng-package.json`
3. Add `assets:["style.scss"]` property
4. run `ng build @your-library-name --prod`
5. You will see `style.scss` in your `dist/@your-library-name`.
6. Then it is importable

<sub>ng-package.json</sub>

```json
{
  "$schema": "../../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../../dist/logo-software/accordion",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts"
  },
  "whitelistedNonPeerDependencies": [
    "@logo-software/theme"
  ],
  "assets": [
    "style.scss"
  ]
}
```

If you want to use this `style.scss` in your current library:
Add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to the top main `@Component` of your library.

<sub>accordion.component.ts</sub>

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'logo-accordion',
  templateUrl: './accordion.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./accordion.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class AccordionComponent implements OnInit {}
```

And the last thing you can use now this `style.scss` at any component.

<sub>accordion.component.scss</sub>

```
// `@import "~@logo-software/theme/style";` for external import

@import "../../style"; // path to the style.scss file

:host{
}
```

Comment: We have it set up this way as well but I am having trouble with SCSS changes triggering --watch. It LOOKS like the library recompiles but the dist folder isn't getting the changes. Did your solution work with watch?